# How to use Google transliteration API in my java web application?

Tags: java, google-api, transliteration

How to use **Google Transliteration** API in my Java application.

If i give a **String** (either in **English or Arabic**) as input, the Google Transliterator API then it should translate it into the corresponding other language and give the **transliterated string** to me. I also want to know is it better to use Google Translator or transliterator?

How to do this? Any Suggestions Please. I need to use this in my JAVA program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a [Java API](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/source/browse/trunk/language/language/src/com/google/gwt/language/client/transliteration/text/Transliteration.java). See the docs [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/LanguageJavadoc) for how to use it.

An example of how to use it is included in the [test code](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/source/browse/trunk/language/language/test/com/google/gwt/language/client/transliteration/text/TransliterationTest.java).

Comment: I am finding hard to implement that. I need the transliterator without button and if I give the input string it should automatically transliterate the value and give the output. Can you help out?

Comment: Google Code is shut down. Can you please repost the example?

Comment: Hi @marcog , i followed your links but they don't work actually , have you another link to provide please ?

Comment: @IamIronMAN - Did you find a way to give the input String and get the transliterated output?