# Transliteration for Java

Tags: java, gwt, google-api, transliteration, icu4j

I have a requirement of `Transliterate` any given word in any language to English using Google transliterator or any other alternative tool. I've tried searching for a solution for this but couldn't find any. There are a lot of solutions for Google Translate API but what I need is `Transliteration`.

All I need is to give a String (ex: Arabic) as input, the Google Transliterator API then it should transform it into English as output.

Found this [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288425/how-to-use-google-transliteration-api-in-my-java-web-application) but couldn't get it to work and most of the links don't work anymore...
Found [this](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started) but I need to use it in a java console application.

Any Suggestions Please? I need to use this in a JAVA program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google transliteration API in Java Swing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134899/google-transliteration-api-in-java-swing-project)

Comment: Since you are using GWT, cannot you use javascript solution directly? Do you want to call this API on client or server side?

Comment: That API has been deprecated since 2011.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen do you have more details? Does it have replacement?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665746/google-cloud-transliteration-api) it's still usable, but who knows for how long...

Comment: @Piro I'll try the 1st one you suggested and update this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't find any working solution with Google Transliterator but found an alternative,  [ICU4J Transliterator](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Transliterator.html). It doesn't support all the languages but works fine with most of the languages.

I've made a [sample project](https://github.com/crteezy/java-translator-transliterator-api) with the ICU4J transliterator and Google Translator. [Check it out](https://github.com/crteezy/java-translator-transliterator-api) if anyone interested.